# EnterpriseLibrary 6 error: Cannot access a disposed object (Object name: 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter')

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

- I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application
- The app uses Logging Application Block and Exception Application Block
- In the production environment I found the following error message happening multiple times:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>           Object name: 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter'.
>           at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.ExecuteReadOperation(Action
>   readOperation)
>              at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.Write(LogEntry
>   log)
>              at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler.WriteToLog(String
>   logMessage, IDictionary exceptionData)
>              at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception
>   exception, Guid handlingInstanceId)
>              at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry.ExecuteHandlerChain(Exception
>   ex, Guid handlingInstanceID)

The error seems to happen when there is an asynchronous request which fails on the server. When the server tries to handle this error, ExceptionHandling app block fails.

The problem I have is, of course, that I don't understand the reason for this error, but what bugles me the most is the fact that I cannot replicate the error.

I have tried re-initializing the AppDomain (via web.config), recycling the App pool, restarting the IIS server just before the ajax request is sent. I have also created a LogWriterWrapper singleton to set the LogWriter instance but the behavior is the same. From time to time, the error when trying to handle the exception still occurs.

I don't know if it could be related, but it seems this error only occurs when the client is ie8/ie9. It never occurred when chrome was used for example, but I guess this might be just by chance alone...

Comment: It seems that this happens if I instantiate the LogWriter once, then instantiate the ExceptionManager (which uses the already existent instance of LogWriter) and then I instantiate again the LogWriter. After this, on the next usage of ExceptionPolicy.HandleException. I have this error probably because the ExceptionManager is still hooked to an instance of LogWriter which is not present any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, for anyone who encounters this issue, in my case it was because in some parts of the application, there was another instantiation of the LogWriter

```
Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create(), false);
```

Because I had some static helpers for logging and exception handling, where I initialized logwriter and also exceptionmanager, whenever an exception occurred durring the app use, which needed to be handled by the exceptionmanager, after the second manual instantiation has already ran, the exceptionamanger was still "hooked" on an instance of logwriter which was not present any more

Comment: So how you resolved this? I'm having the same issue and I can't think of a way to solve this.

Comment: @samithagun I removed the additional instantiation, which happened only in some catch blocks

Answer (score 1):

The exception is self-explanatory - when `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter` is called it was previously disposed somewhere in the code. So you should be searching for something like `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.Dispose()` or eventually `using (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter) { }`

Comment: Unfortunately, I did this check already. I'm not doing any manual dispose nor am I doing any using statements in conjunction with LogWriter or with any other EntLib object

Comment: And also, if this was the reason, I would not have this problem from time to time, I would always have it and it would not be difficult to replicate it ... I would just have to run the app